# How max-heap implement with a following Tournament?

Tags: c++

I want to read in a text document containing players and their budget. Player should store in a binary max-heap. The heap is prioritized by the player’s current budget and must be an array based heap. I add part of the code but I have following confusions:

1. Does my reading in the constructor is right ?
2. Does copy constructor right ?
3. I am not having any idea how to proceed. Could somebody points out what should I do next ?

This is Heap.h

```
#ifndef HEAP
#define HEAP

class Heap{
    public:
        Heap(string filename);// read the name and budget 
        Heap(const Heap &copy);
        void addPlayer(Player* newPlayer); // add player to the heap
        Player getPlayer();
        bool empty();
        unsigned int size(); // return number of nodes in heap
        void RemovePriorityPlayer(int heighest);
        // you still need heasp
        std::vector<Player> getArray();
};

#endif
```

This is Heap.cpp

```
Heap::Heap(string filename) 
{
   std::ifstream str;
   str.open(filename, ifstream::in);
   str.close();
}

Heap(const Heap &copy)
{
   std::if stream copy.str;
}

void addPlayer(Player* newPlayer) // add player to the heap
{
    string name;
    int budget;
    cin>>name>>budget;
    Player* pNewPlayer = new Player(name,budget);

    //if list is empty, make head of list this new player

    if(m-pHead == 0){
        m-pHead = pNewPlayer;
        m-pTail = m-pHead->GetNext();
    }
    else // otherwise find the end of the list and add the player there
    {
        m-pTail = pNewPlayer;
        m-pTail = m-pTail->GetNext();
    }
}
```

Player.h

```
#ifndef PLAYERS
#define PLAYERS

class Player{
    public:
        int Card_hand;
        Player(string name, int budget);
        string getName();
        int getBudget();
        bool bet(int amount);
        void collectWinnings(int amount); 
};

#endif
```

Comment: Answers to your questions: (1) no; (2) no; (3) that's a bit open-ended.

Comment: So many errors here. Try to compile this with all warnings enabled. You will get many errors. Fix those then come back here with specific questions.